# C# #if directive: Can I write an or statement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in a Unity3d project I have the following code, so the code that gets compiled will be different depending on what platform you are on.

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE 
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]   
    #else
    [DllImport ("mylibrary")]
    #endif
```

I'm wondering if something like this is possible and if so what is the correct syntax

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE or UNITY_EDITOR_OSX or UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]   
    #else
    [DllImport ("mylibrary")]
    #endif
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
#if (UNITY_IPHONE || UNITY_EDITOR_OSX || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX)
   //other stuff
#else
   //more other stuff
#endif
```

See [the Microsoft documentation for C# preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) for more information.

Comment: The parentheses are optional, by the way.

Comment: @Darek.. there are no examples of it here.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx

Comment: @GuyeIncognito ... and you usually give up on a book after reading the first page, right? BTW, your link points at C/C++ pre-processor  docs. The one from ed shows the conditional samples from C#.